How to publish(schedule) a Reel in instagram and facebook (cross-post) via API?
My goal is:
I want to schedule a Reel on Instagram and Facebook at a given time (cross-post at same time) via API. Accounts are connected to each other.
If I use the business suite UI I can schedule into both and I see them marked as "cross post"

I want to do the same thing via API.
What I tried

I can publish instagram reel fine using this api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/#reels-posts BUT I see no way of scheduling there
I can schedule or publish Facebook Reel totally fine via the FB GRaph api BUT can't cross-post to instagram at the same time

I can't find any information for the "share to connected" facebook functionality, or cross-posting scheduling the reel at once in both instagram&facebok.
If I schedule Facebook "Reel/Post" via API is not cross-posted. (see below)

I also can't find any way to schedule Instagram Reel via api
NOTE:
I have already connected my instagram and facebook page and can access both as 1 via business suite.
Questions:

How to cross-schedule reel in both instagram and facebook ? To have same functionality as the ui
If point 1 is not possible, at least how to schedule instagram reel so it is posted automatically at a certain date ? I don't see any documented field in the api for this. I read this https://business.instagram.com/blog/instagram-api-features-updates but no information how to schedule a "reel post" at a given time

Thanks in advance

If it is not in the public documentation, it might not be possible is what my understanding is.

There are several things not mentioned in the public api that still work by searching the forums.. that is why I asked here.

Found this query parameter scheduled_publish_time might be the one you're searching for.
The API seems to work with Reels scheduled post Removes references to remixing.
publishReelsUrl = basePublishReelsURI + `&scheduled_publish_time=${scheduled_publish_time}&video_state=SCHEDULED`


This is for facebook and I mentioned that already know it. I need it for Instagram reel

Read point 2 in "What I tried", I mentioned that for facebook works fine but that parameter is not for insta

I read what you wrote, this is the same endpoint as for publishing Reels on Instagram (in the doc there is the IG account ID in the request) so it must be the same thing

That's just deduction from here, as not everything is exposed in the documentation. If you don't want to exchange about that before finding a solution, perhaps forums are not the right place to ask your questions.

use any cron job or any python script to run that api at a specific time of the day
you can also use aws lambda functions to post posts for u on daily basis

I am aware of this but it is not a proper solution. If you see my question Facebook API supports a parameter, I am looking to see if Instagram api supports as well. It is never a good idea to introduce extra infrastructure if it is not mandatory
